# Adding a Query String to a Landing Page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

What is the best way to go about doing this.

I have landing pages for affiliates on my site such as the following:
http://domain.com/businessname

I would like to add a Query String so that the URL is something like the following:
http://domain.com/businessname?affiliatetracking=1

If I try to use a redirect it breaks the site.

Is there an effective way to do this for each of the landing pages?

Thanks,

Comment: How is the site written?

Comment: The site is built in WordPress but, I'm comfortable hopping into the code to make any changes needed to make this happen. Thanks for your help.